# DNS or Virtual host issue to open abc.com and www.abc.com

Tags: domain-name-system, configuration, virtualhost

I'm facing issue with Linux VPS. Whenever I'm clicking **xyz.com**, it is working fine. Whenever I'm trying to click **www.xyz.com**, it is opening firstly configured website on virtual host.

I configured virtual host. whatever ServerName I am giving

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx>
    ServerAdmin info@abc.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www.abc.com/
    ServerName abc.com
    ErrorLog logs/abc_com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx>
    ServerAdmin 5info@xyz.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www.xyz.com/
    ServerName xyz.com
    ErrorLog logs/xyz_com
</VirtualHost>
```

I already made entries in /etc/hosts

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx www.abc.com
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx www.xyz.com
```

both are same IP address

At domain panel, both A and CNAME entries are correct.

Comment: For `ServerName` directive, *xyz.com != www.xyz.com*. Please take some time to look the [official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername) about how `VirtualHost` and `ServerName` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for server aliases. In your configuration, set up a configuarion alias to www. for example

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.tld
    ServerAlias www.domain.tld *.domain.tld
    DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>
```

source: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html